# Proper Matplotlib axes construction / reuse

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I currently am building a set of scatter plot charts using pandas `plot.scatter`. In this construction off of two base axes.

My current construction looks akin to

```
ax1 = pandas.scatter.plot()  
ax2 = pandas.scatter.plot(ax=ax1)


for dataframe in list:
   output_ax = pandas.scatter.plot(ax2)
   output_ax.get_figure().save("outputfile.png")


total_output_ax = total_list.scatter.plot(ax2)
total_output_ax.get_figure().save("total_output.png")
```

This seems inefficient. For 1...N permutations I want to reuse a base axes that has 50% of the data already plotted. What I am trying to do is:

1. Add base data to scatter plot
2. For item x in y: (save data to base scatter and save image)
3. Add all data to scatter plot and save image

Answer (score 0):

here's one way to do it with plt.scatter.
I plot column 0 on x-axis, and all other columns on y axis, one at a time.
Notice that there is only 1 ax object, and I don't replot all points, I just add points using the same axes with a for loop.
Each time I get a corresponding png image.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
np.random.seed(2)
testdf = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(20,4))
```

testdf.head(5) looks like this

```
    0   1   2   3
0   0.435995    0.025926    0.549662    0.435322
1   0.420368    0.330335    0.204649    0.619271
2   0.299655    0.266827    0.621134    0.529142
3   0.134580    0.513578    0.184440    0.785335
4   0.853975    0.494237    0.846561    0.079645
```

```
#I put the first axis out of a loop, that can be in the loop as well
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
ax.scatter(testdf[0],testdf[1], color='red')
fig.legend()
fig.savefig('fig_1.png')
colors = ['pink', 'green', 'black', 'blue']
for i in range(2,4):
    ax.scatter(testdf[0], testdf[i], color=colors[i])
    fig.legend()
    fig.savefig('full_' + str(i) + '.png')
```

Then you get these 3 images (fig_1, fig_2, fig_3)

[image: fig_1]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am looking to create a set of individual images and then create one that is fully combined. Right now I am generating a new axes for each and saving the figure. Then I am generating a new axes that has all of them on it.

Answer (score 0):

Axes objects cannot be simply copied or transferred. However, it is possible to set artists to visible/invisible in a plot. Given your ambiguous question, it is not fully clear how your data are stored but it seems to be a list of dataframes. In any case, the concept can easily be adapted to different input data.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#test data generation
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
rng = np.random.default_rng(123456)
df_list = [pd.DataFrame(rng.integers(0, 100, (7, 2))) for _ in range(3)]

#plot all dataframes into an axis object to ensure 
#that all plots have the same scaling
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
patch_collections = []
for i, df in enumerate(df_list):
    pc = ax.scatter(x=df[0], y=df[1], label=str(i))
    pc.set_visible(False)
    patch_collections.append(pc)

#store individual plots
for i, pc in enumerate(patch_collections):
    pc.set_visible(True)
    ax.set_title(f"Dataframe {i}")
    fig.savefig(f"outputfile{i}.png")
    pc.set_visible(False)

#store summary plot
[pc.set_visible(True) for pc in patch_collections]
ax.set_title("All dataframes")
ax.legend()
fig.savefig(f"outputfile_0_{i}.png")
plt.show()
```