# How can I plot several files in one graph?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I am reading some files and I would like to plot every file into one 2x2 Figure.

```
def plot_Cu_Blk(file):
    global fullname
    global outfile
    global entries

    
    pd.options.display.float_format = '{:.2f}'.format
    data = pd.read_csv(file, sep='\t', names=['Time', '60Ni', '61Ni', '62Ni', '63Cu', '64Ni', '65Cu', '66Zn'],  skiprows=6, dtype=str, index_col=False)

    limit = 30 #only use first 600 rows
    for i in range(0,len(data)):
        if data.values[i][0] == '***':
            limit = i
            break

    qdata = data[:limit].astype(float)
    Ni60 = qdata[['60Ni']]
    Ni61 = qdata[['61Ni']]
    Ni62 = qdata[['62Ni']]
    Cu63 = qdata[['63Cu']]
    Ni64 = qdata[['64Ni']]
    Cu65 = qdata[['65Cu']]
    Zn66 = qdata[['66Zn']]
    Time = qdata[['Time']]


    fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 2, sharex = True, figsize = (13, 8))
    plt.rcParams['figure.dpi'] = 100 
    plt.title(file)
    ax[0, 0].scatter(Time, Ni60)
    ax[0, 1].scatter(Time, Ni61)
    ax[1, 0].scatter(Time, Cu63)
    ax[1, 1].scatter(Time, Cu65)
    
    for axis in ax.flat: axis.set_xlim(0, 32)
    ax[0, 0].set_ylim(0, 0.02)
    ax[1, 0].set_ylim(0, 0.02)
    ax[0, 1].set_ylim(0, 0.002)
    ax[1, 1].set_ylim(0, 0.02)

    
    ax[0, 0].set_xlabel('Time (s)')
    ax[0, 1].set_xlabel('Time (s)')
    ax[1, 0].set_xlabel('Time (s)')
    ax[1, 1].set_xlabel('Time (s)')
    ax[0, 0].set_ylabel('Spannung (V)')
    ax[0, 1].set_ylabel('Spannung (V)')
    ax[1, 0].set_ylabel('Spannung (V)')
    ax[1, 1].set_ylabel('Spannung (V)')

    ax[0, 0].set_title('$^{60}$Ni', color = 'b')
    ax[0, 1].set_title('$^{61}$Ni', color = 'b')
    ax[1, 0].set_title('$^{63}$Cu', color = 'b')
    ax[1, 1].set_title('$^{65}$Cu', color = 'b')
        
    plt.show()
    fig.savefig(outfile + "blank.png", dpi=150)
```

and this function is called by:

```
def element(elements):
    global infile
    global outfile
    inf = infile

    if elements == Cu_Blk: 
        entries = Path(inf)
        for file in entries.glob("*.txt"):
           plot.plot_Cu_Blk(file)
```

This gives me one 2x2 plot for each single file which will overwrite the previous one.

- Question #1: How can I plot all files in the same 2x2 plot with the
  filename as legend?
- Question #2: How can I save each 2x2 fig with the filename as title?
- Question #3: How can I clean up the .set_xlim    part?

Comment: First question: Create `fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 2...)` outside the loop `for filename in entries...`. Second question: `for axis in ax.flat: axis.set_xlim(0, 32)`. Your `ax` object is a normal 2x2 array of (axis) objects.

Comment: Thx for the answer. But placing it outside the loop results again in a single file of the last input file.

Comment: You changed the code from a loop that did not contain plt.show to a function that contains it. Obviously, the same principles apply to the loop and the loop calling the function. Everything figure-related should be outside the loop, so you only call it once and the loop/function is only used to fill the axes with your plotted data.

Comment: Wait - now you want to save each figure separately? I suggest you first define for yourself what you want to achieve and then ask the question.

Comment: I want both :-)

Comment: If you don't want to generate each figure two times (individual and summary figure), you can use the approach suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71363908/8881141 This is a bit more complex in your case as you have also multiple axis objects.